# Set RecyclerView height dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have use `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView` .I set 50 items to the list. But `RecyclerView` doesn't show all item. Only 5 items are display in the screen. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQSMc.png).

My layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/business_recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            />
```

My Java class:

```
bcontractor = new ArrayList<>();
badapter = new HomeBusinessAdapter(context, bcontractor);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 1);
mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
businessdirList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
businessdirList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
businessdirList.setAdapter(badapter);
```

What can be done to display all items ?

Comment: use nestedscrollview

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `RecyclerView` in `ScrollView` but use it in `NestedScrollView` while disabling the nesting scroll for the  `RecyclerView` & also, you should set the `RecyclerView` height to `wrap_content`  so it only takes what it should take instead of just taking the whole parent height.

So your `layout` should be something like `NestedScrollView->ViewGroupLayout->RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

Probable solution  ( I used to have the same problem as you )

1. When you create a recyclerview, you will need a specific layout for the item you want to display. check that xml and see the height of the parent of that layout
2. Does your scrollview's height set to match parent?

Comment: Yes it is match parent

Comment: Scroll view is a view group that extends frame layout.

Comment: Scroll view is a view group that extends frame layout, it is possible the scrollview is blocking the recyclerview's on touch event.

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html

Here is the example:
 Add this      `implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'`
to your dependencies.

And this is your reyclerview configuration :

```
val layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(this)
layoutManager.flexDirection = FlexDirection.ROW
layoutManager.justifyContent = JustifyContent.FLEX_START
recyclerview.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

You can check this gist also https://gist.github.com/siifii/3edd8cd2d4f5a9b4672b9976c0c55ff4

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `ScrollView` with `NestedScrollView` and set your recyclerview `height` to `wrap_content`